# I'm getting an error on my response from Retrofit Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I've looked at several answers, I'm missing something. Also is there a way to see the data prior to Retrofit handling it?

Here's the code

```
extends Activity implements Callback<List<MemberPOJO>> {

@Inject
MembersInterface memberInterfaceService;

@Override
public void onFailure(Exception ex) {

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

    String retrofitError = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();

    Log.e("LoadActivity", retrofitError);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(List<MemberPOJO> result) {

    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(result.size());

    Log.e("LoadActivity", "MemberPOJO:" + result);

}
```

...

```
public void getMemberHostData() {
    MemberLoader loader = new MemberLoader(this, memberInterfaceService);

    RetrofitLoaderManager.init(getLoaderManager(), 0, loader, this);
}

static class MemberLoader extends RetrofitLoader<List<MemberPOJO>, MembersInterface> {

    public MemberLoader(Context context, MembersInterface service) {

        super(context, service);
    }



    RestAdapter.Builder builder= new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;versions=1");
                    request.addHeader("authorization",getAuthorization(getContext()));

                }
            });

    @Override
    public List<MemberPOJO> call(MembersInterface service) {

        return service.listOfMemebers();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your response is either not valid JSON, or doesnt match your response object. You can use a third party tool such as Charles to snoop the network traffic, or I believe the Retrofit exception has a response body on it.

Comment: You can see everything in both the HTTP request and response (including the body) by setting the RestAdapter's log level to full.

Comment: Kool. My guts telling me your right. Is there a way in retrofit to just pull back a string or just the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull string if you have `StringConverter` and [StringTypedOutput](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/18029c3926eacf1b7fc0). This will deliver plain string and it won't deserialize anything. Of course you can try to validate if JSON is valid inside `fromBody()` method, if it is valid then just proceed with deserialization (extends it to `GsonConverter`), otherwise just get the `Response`

```
public class StringConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput arg0, Type arg1)
            throws ConversionException {

        return getStringFromInputStream(arg0.in());
    }

    @Override
    public TypedOutput toBody(Object arg0) {
        String string = (String) arg0;
        return new StringTypedOutput(string.getBytes(Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8)));
    }


    public static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //close the stream if needed.
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
}
```