# Retrofit and TypedInput

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

From the documentation, The **TypedInput** and **TypedOutput** classes exist only to bind a mime type to data.
When we have to use the **TypedInput** in the Request. ?? Why we need this mapping while making the Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have consistent MIME type for all requests then you shouldn't bother about the `TypedInput` or `TypedOutput`. Let's say if you have JSON in and out for your request you should not consider using these. But if you have mixed requests, let's say [byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165438/get-base64-image-using-retrofit-error-com-google-gson-jsonsyntaxexception-java/28186334#28186334), JSON and XML you should provide [your own Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649881/im-getting-an-error-on-my-response-from-retrofit-expected-begin-array-but-was-s) and mapping for different requests.

Comment: When I used to make a POST request, in which my @Body of the request is Json, I had used the below approach

@POST("/verify/email")
void verifyEmail(@Body VerifyUser Verify, Callback<Session> responseCallback);


This is working perfectly well.

But I had seen people using TypedInput in the body of the request. So I'm confused when I have to use this ?? Which one is the good approach