# How to properly handle text/plain responses with retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a webservice call which response is plain text and no json. In the callback below, failure() always gets called even with successful responses because retrofit tries to parse the response as json.

```
new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
        ...    
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        ...
        }
    });
```

The following error occurs:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 16 path $

How can I tell retrofit, that the response is plain text and should not be treated as json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `GsonConverter` for deserializing and `Gson` fails to validate the response as Json format.  thats why you are getting MalformedJsonException. You need to supply something like this [StringConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649881/im-getting-an-error-on-my-response-from-retrofit-expected-begin-array-but-was-s) in your `RestAdapter`